# How to accomplish this layout with CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

I would like to accomplish this layout with CSS and HTML.

[image]

I started a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/c8rHj/) which is a start, but I don't know how to make the fonts look more like the goal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Register</title>

    <script src="/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/scripts/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<h3 class="marg-left title"><img src="/images/logga.png"> Account Administration</h3>
<hr />

<a href="/admin/adduser">Add new account</a> <br> <a href="/admin/search">Search account</a> <br> <a href="/admin/search">Export</a> <br> <a href="/admin/search">Import</a> <br>  <a href="/admin/search">Setup</a> <br> <a href="/admin/adminmenu">Log out</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need to acquire fonts that look like you want. You can use a service like http://dafont.com or purchase one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c8rHj/6/ hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a fiddle that closely matches your UI mockup. Unfortunately futura is not a very freely accessible web font, so I have instead used a google font called `Raleway`.

For the single button links on the sidebar I have created button modules, just add or delete these as you wish. Hope you find it useful!

```
<!-- SINGLE BUTTON MODULE -->
<a href="#"><div class="navigation-button">
<div class="navigation-header">Add new account</div>
<div class="navigation-desc">Add new user account</div>
</div></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HEue6/1/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think *futura* is a default font. You need to include the fonts you want to use. I recommend google fonts since it worked great for me in the past, but there're many services like this. Here's a brief how-to for including it in your page:

1. Go here:

   > http://www.google.com/fonts
2. Find the font you want (futura is not in google, it is external).
3. Click in "add to collection".
4. Click "use" on the bottom right of the page
5. Then copy something like this in your webpage (before the css):

   ```
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   ```
6. Finally put this in your css:

   ```
   font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
   ```